# Socket "Could not connect 101" error. How to fix this?

Tags: php, sockets

I just want a very simple client to connect and read data from a TCP server that I know its up and running fine.

Here's my piece of code:

```
if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket created \n";

if(!socket_connect($sock , 'my.ip.goes.here' , port))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Could not connect: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Connection established \n";
```

I get the socket created fine, error when connecting though: "Could not connect: [110] Connection timed out"

Edit: Could it be a problem with my host? If so, I could try finding the problem there.

Edit: My host seems fine, it does allow sockets to be used. Any more tips?

Comment: Did you tried to use `telnet your.ip.x.y port` to see if your server is up and running? Your code looks good.

Comment: I have a client in C# and connected to the server. It's receiving and writing data just fine. Still, yes I was able to connect with telnet.

Comment: Try to force defining a protocol as third argument of socket_create. `SOL_TCP` or `SOL_UDP` according to your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot test it right now, but probably it's because you didn't specify the protocol. In this case,

```
socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
```

will do the trick...

Comment: Is `port` a variable? Did you miss the `$` before that?